# Android is it possible to have a part of the layout scrollable

Tags: android

I am trying to make an android application and I need the middle part of my screen to be scrollable. When I set a ScrollView inside an Relative Layout my application crashes.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCijferHalen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etWegingTehalenCijfer"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPressedHighlight"
    android:paddingStart="65dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="?attr/editTextColor"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/etWatStaan"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etWatStaan"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="328dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:paddingStart="65dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="?attr/editTextColor"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvCijferHalen"
    android:layout_above="@+id/etWatStaan"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvCijferHalen">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etcijfer1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="185dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Cijfer 1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/etcijfer1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etcijfer1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="187dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bLess1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="weging"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLess1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etcijfer2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etcijfer1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etcijfer1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Cijfer 2"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etweging2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bLess2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="weging"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLess2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etweging2"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etcijfer3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etcijfer1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etcijfer2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Cijfer 3"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etweging3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etweging2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bLess2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="weging"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLess3"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etweging3"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etcijfer4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etcijfer1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etcijfer3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Cijfer 4"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etweging4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etweging3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bLess3"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="weging"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLess4"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etweging4"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etcijfer5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etcijfer1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etcijfer4"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Cijfer 5"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etweging5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etweging4"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bLess4"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="weging"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLess5"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etweging5"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etcijfer6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etcijfer1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etcijfer5"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Cijfer 6"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etweging6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etweging5"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bLess5"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="weging"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLess6"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etweging6"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etcijfer7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etcijfer1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etcijfer6"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Cijfer 7"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etweging7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etweging1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etweging6"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bLess6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="weging"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLess7"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etweging7"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etWatStaan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bNiewCijfer"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etWegingTehalenCijfer"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Wat wil je staan"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etWegingTehalenCijfer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="weging"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/etWatStaan"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etWatStaan"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="187dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bNiewCijfer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Cijfer Toevoegen"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvCijferHalen"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvCijferHalen"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorMultiSelectHighlight"
    android:text="Te halen Cijfer"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="?attr/editTextColor" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:text="Gemiddelde"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="?attr/editTextColor" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvCijferHalen"
    android:layout_marginEnd="71dp"
    android:text="Weging"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:text="Cijfer"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Can someone help me ? I am wondering if it's even possible to have only a part of the screen scrollable

Comment: add your layout and your relevant code and crash logcat, if you want to have answer to your question! otherwise people will down-vote your question and maybe close/delete it as unclear! read these: [ask] & [mcve] & [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

---

**Step 1**

Use a `LinearLayout` as your `root` element to enable you to use `layout_weight`attribute;

**Step 2**

Inside your layout, you can split it into 3 parts each with a `layout_weight` of `.3`

For example:

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   orientation="vertical"
   ... >

   <LinearLayout 
      layout_weight=".3"
      layout_width="match_parent"
      layout_height="0dp" />

   <ScrollView 
      layout_weight=".3"
      layout_width="match_parent"
      layout_height="0dp" />

   <LinearLayout 
      layout_weight=".3"
      layout_width="match_parent"
      layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout> !-- end of root layout here
```

I said .3 just in case you want to have the sections occupy the same size of the window; but you can set them to whatever you want according to your needs.

I hope this helps.

**Note** A `ScrollView` only accepts ONE child element!

Good luck!

Comment: Just accept the answer please so others will find it helpful. Thanks